# Open MP parallel for loop in C running in one thread

Tags: c, openmp, parallel.for

I have this part of a code which is reading a 2D array of structs, doing some math on them that putting the results into a second 2D array:

```
#pragma omp parallel for private (n, i, j) schedule(dynamic)
for(n = 0; n < frames_read; n++){   
    for (i = 0; i < atoms_total; i++)
    {
    for(j = 0; j < atoms_total; j++)
    {

        if (timestep_array[i][n].atom_id == timestep_array[j][m].atom_id)
        {
            // calculates the vector magnitude and stores it in the created array MSD
            double temp1_x = timestep_array[i][n].normalized_x_position + timestep_array[i][n].x_box;
            double temp2_x = timestep_array[j][n+1].normalized_x_position + timestep_array[j][n+1].x_box;
            double temp3_x = temp2_x - temp1_x;
            double temp4_x = temp3_x * box_bound_x;
            double temp5_x = pow(temp4_x, 2);


            double temp1_y = timestep_array[i][n].normalized_y_position + timestep_array[i][n].y_box;
            double temp2_y = timestep_array[j][n+1].normalized_y_position + timestep_array[j][n+1].y_box;
            double temp3_y = temp2_y - temp1_y;
            double temp4_y = temp3_y * box_bound_y;
            double temp5_y = pow(temp4_y, 2);


            double temp1_z = timestep_array[i][n].normalized_z_position + timestep_array[i][n].z_box;
            double temp2_z = timestep_array[j][n+1].normalized_z_position + timestep_array[j][n+1].z_box;
            double temp3_z = temp2_z - temp1_z;
            double temp4_z = temp3_z * box_bound_z;
            double temp5_z = pow(temp4_z, 2);



            double temp = temp5_x + temp5_y + temp5_z;
            double temp2 = sqrt(temp);
            int atom_number = timestep_array[i][n].atom_id;


            MSD[atom_number][n].msd = sqrt(temp2);
            MSD[atom_number][n].atom_type = timestep_array[i][n].atom_type;

            MSD[atom_number][n].time_in_picoseconds = timestep_array[i][n].timestep / picoseconds;


            }


    }

}
```

}

I have tried so many combinations of the #pragma statement (including making many more of the variables private.) Nothing has resulted in the a.out file running more than one thread. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: are you compiling properly, using the correct syntax for enabling `openmp` ?  Let us know specifically what compiler you are using.  Last i checked for gcc 4.3.4 you need to do  `-fopenmp`  when compiling.  This syntax is not the same if you are using the Intel compiler.

Comment: I have tried using 'gcc-6 -fopenmp' and 'clang -openmp'

Comment: `#pragma omp` not `#pragma opm`

Comment: That was a stupid typo lol. Still just one thread. :(

Comment: Have you set OMP_NUM_THREADS?

Comment: try omp_set_num_threads(4); to hard code 4 threads in your code. or set in terminal as @GavinPortwood says.  Also start small, try hello world example first. [download this c code and run the way you run and see the results you get with your current settings]( https://www.dartmouth.edu/~rc/classes/intro_openmp/hello_world_openmp.html)

Comment: I think OpenMP doesn't automatically use all the available threads if you don't ask him. To be sure of it either use omp_set_num_threads(X) as @itsnevertoobadtoaskforhelp told you or add the num_threads(X) directive to your pragma (X being the number of threads you want)

Comment: have you looked at warnings `-Wall`?

Comment: Try `schedule(static)`